# iPhone Xcode view will not space subviews vertically from 3.5" to 4" screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, autolayout, autosize, autoresizingmask

After researching here and other sites, I cannot seem to find an answer that helps me solve my problem or helps me move forward. I may not be using the correct terminology in my search. The info I find seems to focus on autosizing for portrait versus landscape views of the iPhone or iPad, but not so much on vertical re-spacing between the 3.5 and 4 form factors.

I have laid out an example single view in Xcode 4.6.2 to fit nicely on the iPhone Retina 3.5 form factor screen, but when I click to apply the Retina 4 form factor there is an empty space near the bottom. I would have expected all the view items to space out vertically to give a similar pleasant layout. I have tried different constraint setting, even setting the vertical spacings to >= on the view items.

Your help is very much appreciated!

I tried to post screen shot of each of the form factors but my "reputation" is to low.

Answer (score 1):

you need to increase the Size of the User Interface from Storyboard/Xib's Interface ,look for a Rectangle with Two arrows ,and use Either Autolayout ,"springs and struts" or Use Frame and CGRect and do it programatically.  S o!oenter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAQwb.png)ver there

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends upon whether you're using auto layout (iOS 6 and above) or not. If not, look into auto sizing masks (called autosizing in IB, `autoresizingMask` when adjusting a view's mask programmatically, colloquially referred to as "springs and struts").

If not using autolayout, you use "autosizing" settings. For example, this sets that bottom view to automatically resize the height and width for the view, keeping the top, bottom, left, and right margins fixed:

[image: autosizing]

Play around with clicking on the various red arrows and I-beams on the panel on the right, and you can adjust what autosizing you want to take place. The little animated window to the right will show you how the control will adjust size based upon 3.5" or 4.0" screen.

If using auto layout (iOS 6 and above), you set up constraints to the superview accordingly:

[image: autolayout]

Setting up constraints in auto layout is a little confusing the first time you use it, but I'd refer you to the [Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html). There are links to wonderful WWDC 2012 video resources, there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never.

I found a code way to your problem of shrinking the vertical spaces between views.

```
#define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

//Shrink your constraints at run time!!
if(!IS_WIDESCREEN)
{
    for(NSLayoutConstraint *c in self.view.constraints)
    {
        if ((c.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTop && c.secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeBottom) || (c.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeBottom && c.secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTop)) 
        {
            if(c.constant > 13) // -> this value is adjustable so that some spaces doesn't shrink too much
            {
                c.constant *= (3.5/4.0);
            }
        }
    }

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

It still can be adjusted but it does the job.

Hope it helps you as it helped me after a lot of struggle.